# Magento 2: Add Reset option in the Auto Generation coupon grid Manage Coupon Codes section

Tags: magento2, coupon-codes, action, reset

I need to add `Reset` option in Manage Coupon Codes Auto Generation coupon grid `Action`.

When select record(coupon code) in the grid and click on the `Reset` option then `Submit` button should be display and click on submit button to reset the coupon code.

Reset button reset the selected coupon code `Time Used: 0` so customer can again able to used this coupon code.

If any have idea how can add `Reset` button in Action dropdown for reset coupon code set `Time Used: 0` then let me know.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For the Reset Button functionality, you must create a custom module and put your logic into it to cater to the Scenario for **Time Used: 0**.

Just break down your tasks or module functionality as follows:

- Create an option for Admin Grid: Add an extra column or Action button.
- Assign the coupon code that is selected through the code and access the coupon functionality.

I hope that will help you!